# Which Stack Exchange site is appropriate for asking Blackberry/BIS questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I have a question on [BIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry_Internet_Service)/[BlackBerry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry). Is Super User appropriate for that?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, smart phone OSes and cell phones are not on-topic for Super User, so such a question would not fit here. If you're interested in helping create a Stack Exchange for BlackBerry questions, check out this Area 51 proposal: [BlackBerry Enthusiasts](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38297/blackberry-enthusiasts?referrer=HFy8v9lY6rbNOBoJbkgQLQ2).

Comment: Bummer, that's what I figured. Oh well, thanks.

Comment: That's been deleted. Maybe a more general SmartPhone one should be proposed to cover BB,Nokia, and to a lesser extent Android and iPhone questions?

Answer (score 5):

Server Fault seems more appropriate if you are looking at BIS issues.